# Rotating UI element using touch for mobile - Unity 2D

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I want to create the above object that will rotate on z-axis following the direction of a finger. Like a dial. I have written the following code and attached it to that element:

```
private float rotationRate = 3.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        // get the user touch input
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching at: " + touch.position);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Debug.Log("Touch phase began at: " + touch.position);
            }
            else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                Debug.Log("Touch phase Moved");
                transform.Rotate(touch.deltaPosition.y * rotationRate,
                                 -touch.deltaPosition.x * rotationRate, 0, Space.World);
            }
            else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                Debug.Log("Touch phase Ended");
            }
        }
    }
```

But the element does not move at all. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is a gif for better understanding:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this Script and it did rotate the sprite but not like the GIF you have posted so i mad a little bit of changes and it worked fine also the value of "rotationRate" was way to high so reduced it to "0.4f" but is totally up to you what do you like, Any way here is you updated script:

```
[SerializeField, Range(0, 3)] private float rotationRate = 0.4f;

    void Update()
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching at: " + touch.position);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Debug.Log("Touch phase began at: " + touch.position);
            }
            else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                Debug.Log("Touch phase Moved");
                transform.Rotate(0, 0, -touch.deltaPosition.x * rotationRate, Space.World);
            }
            else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                Debug.Log("Touch phase Ended");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried the code again using another device and yes it works. I don't know maybe the issue was with the device.

Comment: Ok. I am glad it worked. If my answar helped you out then accept and up vote my answar.

Comment: another small question, it will not be worth asking as a new question so I am asking here. If I want to limit the movement of z-angle between `-45 and 45` how can I do it? I tried limiting `transform.eulerAngles.z` between them but it causes abnormal behavior.

Comment: Have you tried Mathf.Clamp? here is documentation about it: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html

Comment: `Math.Clamp` resets the angle to `-45` after increasing form `0`. I Found another solution online, Needed a little modification but it worked.